# Setup rules/alerts before raising a PR in Github

Tags: github, git-merge, pull-request

Basically whenever somebody raises a PR on my repository, I want to ensure that the person raising the PR has performed some actions (running a script etc.)

So is there a way to set up some rule or some alert so as to remind the person to perform that action before raising the PR.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something called *integration*. Here you can see the [GitHub Integrations Directory](https://github.com/integrations).

My favorite is [Travis CI](https://github.com/integrations/travis-ci)–you set it up using a `.travis.yml` file and then **after** the commits are pushed the tests are run and Travis sends the status response which will be visible to in the Pull request.

However, this can't stop the user to submit the pull request.

---

Like I mentioned, you cannot stop the user to open pull requests but you can tell him/her the steps how to contribute using the `CONTRIBUTING.md` in your project. Then when somebody opens a pull request or issue will see this alert:

> [image]

Comment: I don't want to use some CI setup. I was looking if there is something inbuilt within github. Anyways, thanks for the response! :)

Comment: @VinilNarang No, there is no such a thing currently. Maybe you want to use a `CONTRIBUTING.md` file (see the edit).